# Is Microsofts' adaptive cards natively supported in telegram?

Tags: telegram, adaptive-cards

Now that I got totally stuck with above mentioned question I hope that someone can bring some light into that topic.

Looking into Microsofts documentation of their botframework one can see that telegram is one of many channels that it supports. But for some reason I do not want to use the Botframwork, but still like the adaptive card concept for its idea to decouple channel rendering from card design.

I did some research of how it should work and came across how it works in Cisco WebEx Teams, where the cards are natevily supported - simply sending it as json according to ciscos' API docs.

But how is this working with Telegram? On the Telegram docs is no indication that there is any support for it.

Any ideas ?

Comment: It looks like nobody is facing this problem at all ..

Comment: After reading back and force all kind of docs and following hints I came to the conclusion that this feature is not supported as nobody has written a renderer for this .. and after some further readings I started successfully to use the inline keyboard functionality being provided from telegram sdk